# In Android, Admob is giving error: Failed to load ad: 0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, admob

I'm using AdMob in my app but few days ago ads stopped loading and give th following error.

```
Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Ads are loading in emulator and test device,but not on other devices.I tried to the unit-ids by creating a new app on AdMob account as well but getting same issue. What could be the issue?

Piece of code is:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.admob_test_device))
                    .build();
            mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: have you got any solution for this type of error ?

Comment: @Anand it happens in following cases:
- Either you unit id is incorrect.
- If you have created Unit Ids just now, then wait for few hours as it take a while to be live.
- If you Ads were showing before but not now, then are you testing live Ads and clicking on live Ads from test device?, if yes then Admob might have detected it as spam and has blocked the unit ids for your app.
- AdView is not provided a required space to show load and show the Ad.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It's solved